# Differential equation - can't find mistake

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got this differential equation: $$xy'=y-x\exp{\frac{y}{x}}$$ I used $\frac{y}{x}=z$ to solve it and the answer I get is $$y=\frac{x}{\ln(\ln(x))}$$ (while it should be $y=-x\ln(\ln(Cx))$. I think that I make mistake after integration:

$$\begin{align*}
\exp(-z) &= \ln(Cx)\\\\
\frac{1}{\exp(z)} &= \ln(Cx)\\\\
\frac{1}{\exp(y)\exp(1/x)} &= \ln(Cx)\\\\
\frac{\exp(x)}{\exp(y)} &= \ln(Cx)\\\\
\frac{x}{y} &= \ln(\ln(Cx))\\\\
y &= \frac{x}{\ln(\ln(Cx))}
\end{align*}$$

Help? Thanks:)

Comment: Named math operators should appear upright, and the common ones have their own code for this purpose (e.g. `\exp`, `\ln` - [see entry 11 in our MathJax guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first mistake occurs when you write $\exp(z) = \exp(y) \exp(1/x)$.  This is not correct, since $$\exp(y) \exp(1/x) = \exp(y + 1/x) \ne \exp(y/x).$$

Instead, just take the logarithm of both sides from the very start:  $$\exp(-z) = \ln (Cx)$$ implies $$-z = \ln \ln (Cx).$$  Then write $-z = -y/x$, and the rest follows easily.

Comment: Just as I thought. Thank you!